# JSON object to be sent to webservice from Java client

Tags: java, web-services

Suggestions requested:

I have a webservice call to be invoked from JAVA Client. Please suggest various ways I can connect with the `Webservice` Interface and pass the parameters. I have currently generated objects from `wsdl` on the client side and connect to the server. However it generates complex data types as `ArrayofArray` appended to the objects.

Can JSON be used and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using wsdl, i assume you are using some JAX-WS implementation.
If it is the reference implementation (metro from glassfish), it has a nice way to work with JSON, here is the link:

https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/

But your question is a little bit confusing, i didn't exactly an understand your situation, post your generated data type, and some code, and we can try to help you a little bit more.

Comment: The structure generated by the WSDL looks something like below <ns2:ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
 <ns2:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType> whereas the object accepted by the .net server code has a different structure.Now if I want to use  JSON let me try with the link above